# MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading, zoom

Tags: ios, zooming, mapkit, tracking

I use MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading so that the map follows the user location and rotates. Problem is zoom level is not sticking. here is my code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.locMapView.delegate = self;
[self.locMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

}

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate(_locMapView.userLocation.coordinate);
double w = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(_locMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude) * 500;
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(pt.x - w/2.0, pt.y - w/2.0, w, w);

[_locMapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

}

I tried to set zoom level in viewDidLoad also, not much luck.

How can i make map to stick to zoom level when UserTrackingMode is set to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you don't need to calculate an MKMapRect to set what the map shows.  It's easier to use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance which takes a coordinate and meters directly.  It returns an MKCoordinateRegion which you can use  with setRegion instead of calling setVisibleMapRect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick I did to resolve this problem: Set mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone before zoom in/out then set = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) MKUserTrackingMode lastTrackingMode;

- (IBAction)zoomInButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;

    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.region.center,MKCoordinateSpanMake(self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta*0.5, self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta*0.5));
    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion];

    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = self.lastTrackingMode;
}

- (IBAction)zoomOutButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;

    // Zoom-out code goes here

    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = self.lastTrackingMode;
}
```